# android permission is added on google store but it's not in APK

Tags: android, permissions, google-play, google-play-console

I added   `tools:node="remove" android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"`
to make sure contacts' permission is removed (even though I don't request it at all in any manifest).
When I upload the apk release to the google play console and check the APK information, I can read that my app asks for 25 permissions - none of them is "read_contacts" which is good!

Although when I go to the public page of my app on the Google Store, I  scroll down to permission section this app requests it says- "Contacts- read your contacts"
Why? Where does it come from? This permission is not in the APK
here are my 25 permission that I can see exists in the apk

```
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
android.permission.INTERNET
android.permission.READ_APP_BADGE
android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
android.permission.WAKE_LOCK
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
com.anddoes.launcher.permission.UPDATE_COUNT
com.android.vending.BILLING
com.BiniTheBunny.hoppy.permission.C2D_MESSAGE
com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE
com.google.android.finsky.permission.BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE
com.htc.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS
com.htc.launcher.permission.UPDATE_SHORTCUT
com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.CHANGE_BADGE
com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS
com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS
com.majeur.launcher.permission.UPDATE_BADGE
com.oppo.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS
com.oppo.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS
com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.READ
com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.WRITE
com.sonyericsson.home.permission.BROADCAST_BADGE
com.sonymobile.home.permission.PROVIDER_INSERT_BADGE
me.everything.badger.permission.BADGE_COUNT_READ
me.everything.badger.permission.BADGE_COUNT_WRITE
```

Comment: how long it has been when you updated the app on Google play store?

Comment: It's been 3 weeks

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by myself if any of you want to know-
Apparently, Google combines permissions from all the releases you have in the console,
in my case, I had an old test release (for internal testers) that I even forgot about, and it contained that unwanted permission.  Google added this permission to the permissions list in the store-  even though it's not even published, and even though it's not the version that available in the store...